# Transparent Full Screen Window with GTK4

Tags: c, gtk4

I am using gtk4 on Ubuntu, Wayland. I want to create a full screen transparent window.

With this code, I can create a full screen window, but I don't know how to make it transparent.

1. My draw_callback does not get called. Why?
2. How do I make this window transparent?

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <cairo.h>

static void
print_hello (GtkWidget *widget,
             gpointer   data)
{
  g_print ("Hello World\n");
}

gboolean 
draw_callback(GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *cr, gpointer data)
{
    cairo_set_source_rgba (cr, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    int width = gtk_widget_get_allocated_width(widget);
    int height = gtk_widget_get_allocated_height(widget);
    // cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 1, 0, 0);
    // cairo_move_to(cr, 0, 0);
    // cairo_line_to(cr, 200, 200);
    // cairo_stroke(cr);

    return FALSE;
}

static void
activate (GtkApplication *app,
          gpointer        user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Window");
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 200, 200);

  GtkWidget *button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Hello World");
  g_signal_connect (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (print_hello), NULL);
  gtk_window_set_child (GTK_WINDOW (window), button);

  GtkWidget *drawing_area = gtk_drawing_area_new ();
  gtk_widget_set_size_request (drawing_area, 200, 200);
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (drawing_area), "draw", G_CALLBACK (draw_callback), NULL);

  gtk_window_present (GTK_WINDOW (window));
  gtk_window_fullscreen(GTK_WINDOW(window));

  // cairo_t *cr = gdk_cairo_create(GTK_WINDOW (window));
  // cairo_set_source_rgba (cr, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0); 
  // cairo_set_operator (cr, CAIRO_OPERATOR_SOURCE);
  // cairo_paint (cr);
  // cairo_destroy(cr);

}

int
main (int    argc,
      char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;

  app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_DEFAULT_FLAGS);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
  status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);

  return status;
}
```